# Subgroup of rational number containing integer is the whole group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $H$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}^{*},\cdot)$ such that $\{\mathbb{Z-0}\}$ is contained in $H$. Then $H=\mathbb{Q}^*$

Can the result follow from if $x, y \in H$ then  $xy^{-1}\in H.$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it follows *directly* from that.

Say we have an arbitrary element $\frac{p}{q}\in \Bbb Q^*$, with $p, q\in \Bbb Z-\{0\}$. Then $p, q\in H$, so $pq^{-1}\in H$. But $pq^{-1} = \frac pq$, so $\frac pq\in H$, and we're done.